# setLength() method is StringBuilder and how it works internally

Tags: java

As far as I understand, a StringBuilder object contains an array of characters. And when we construct a StringBuilder object, we specify a capacity(or directly provide a string).
I'm assuming this means an array of the specified capacity length(or default capacity) is also created internally.

If I then append or insert a string of shorter length than the capacity, what's in the (leftover?) empty slots of that array? Is it null(\u0000)?

And if it is null, what happens with setLength(newLength) when the newLength argument is greater than the length of the actual string also confuses me. In the java API documentation, it is stated that "If the newLength argument is greater than or equal to the current length, sufficient null characters(\u0000) are appended to the string builder so that "length" becomes the newLength argument." My question is, aren't there null characters there already?

Any clarifications are appreciated (:

Edit again: meant in* in the title

Comment: Why would it matter what's in the extra spaces?

Comment: Juust wanted to know(:

Comment: why not have a look at the source code? normally shipped with the JDK.

Comment: You can look up the source yourself, either in `src.zip` coming along with your JDK, or in [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#158).  
*Posting this as comment because the accepted answer (with same info) was deleted by a moderator.*

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, aren't there null characters there already?

No, when you shrink or delete chars from the StringBuilder it doesn't have to pad out the chars no longer used with `nul` chars.

Answer (score 0):

According to javadoc of `SpringBuilder`:

`If the newLength argument is greater than or equal to the current length, sufficient null characters ('\u0000') are appended so that length becomes the newLength argument.`

So in fact as StringBuilder stores array of `char` characters, this array will be length of `newLength`.

If your current `StringBuilder` has length 10, and you set this length to 12, the missing  space will be filled by `null` (for `char` type this is `\u0000`).
So the two last chars will be null.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('x');
System.out.println(sb.length()); // prints 1
sb.setLength(2);
System.out.println(sb.length()); // prints 2
```

Comment: I thought the array is the length of the capacity we specify/default capacity if capacity is not specified?  Orr am I missing something?

Comment: Default constructor of StringBuilder set capacity to 16.

Comment: And if I append a string of length 12, let's say, and then setLength to 13, what are in the last three slots of that original array of length 16? I'm sorry! This is super frustrating.

Comment: It is not related - length is not a capacity and this is internal implementation of memory storing in this object. You cannot access characters. Method charAt `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index is negative or greater than or equal to length().`

Comment: But if you even can check it I probably call that will be `null`, but you CAN'T access it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose StringBuilder has an array of length 'n', and 'k' for the new length.
My understanding is then as follows:

- if k>n, then null values ('\u0000') will be appended to fit the length increase
- If k == n, nothing will happen. JavaDoc says "greater than or equal to the current length", but I am not sure anything will happen if the current length is the same as the new length.
- If k < n, the array will be shortened to length k, no null-characters will be added.

Comment: Isn't the length of the array the capacity we specify, and if we don't specify it, 16? For example, let's say I create a StringBuilder using the no-arg constructor. This, I'm assuming, creates an array of length 16 internally. And then, if I call append("Hello"), and afterwards, call the length() method, I'll get 5. Aaand if I then call setLength(6), --this is actually where I'm stuck. According to javadoc, the nul character is added after the 'o' of hello. What's in the 10 slots left of the initial array?

Comment: Length of the array and the capacity of the StringBuilder are two separate things. StringBuilder has the function `ensureCapacity()` for the capacity, and `setLength()` for the array length. The docs say the following:  
Every string builder has a capacity. As long as the length of the
character sequence contained in the string builder does not exceed
the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal
buffer. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger.

Comment: So, to answer your last question. Nothing happens, because those slots never existed in the first place. The capacity is at 16, but the array is of length 6. The only null value that is added is on position [5], after the 'o' of hello. There is no position [6] or after, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to retrieve a value there.

Answer (score 0):

The null characters are added by StringBuilder. `setLength` does the following:

First, use the `Arrays` copy.

```
Arrays.copyOf(value, newLength)
```

and last, set \0 on the last characters:

```
   if (count < newLength) {
                for (; count < newLength; count++)
                    value[count] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the code of setLength method of string builder it does the following

1. ensures new length is positive else throw
   StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
2. ensures that minimum capacity is met for example if the min capacity
   was 10 and you are changing length to 20, a new array is created and
   content of the actual array is copied to it this new array, then it 
   replaces the old array of the string builder. 
   **no new array is created if length is being reduced**
3. it checks if the length of the new array is more than the previous
   array, if yes then it fills the extra indexes of that array with
   null character
4. sets the length of the new array as the current length **( In case the new length is less than the previous length the extra characters are discarded, In short the array is not altered or replaced just the length marker of the array is changed to new length)**

Answer (score 0):

- If the newLength argument is greater than or equal to the current length, sufficient null characters ('\u0000') are appended so that length becomes the newLength argument.
- Execute these set of commands to understand the behaviour of `setLength()` method

  ```
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("tutorials");
    System.out.println("string = " + str);  

    // length of StringBuilder
    System.out.println("length = " + str.length());

    // set the length of StringBuilder to 5
    str.setLength(5);

    // print new StringBuilder value after changing length
    System.out.println("After set, string = " + str);

    // length of StringBuilder after changing length
    System.out.println("length = " + str.length());
  ```

**Output:**

```
string = tutorials
length = 9
After set, string = tutor
length = 5
```